# What does the command "sudo mv home/* *" do?

Tags: linux, terminal, wildcard, sudo, mv

I know each part of this command.

```
sudo mv home/* *
```

- `sudo`: super-user do, execute with root privileges.
- `mv`: move a file or directory.
- `home/*`: argument of mv command. It indicates the content of home directory. The asterisk `*` is a wildcard that expands to the list of files in the current directory in lexicographic order.

The next argument is the destiny folder. However, I specify an asterisk as destiny directory, and if I execute the command the folder disappear completely. So, what does the `*` in this case?

Comment: If the last entry in your current directory is a subdirectory, that would be the destination to which everything else gets moved.

Comment: BTW, in general, this is a better question for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/); StackOverflow's scope is questions *unique to software development*, and both shell globs and the `mv` command are more general than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have `/home/userA`, `/home/userB` and `/home/userC`. Let's further say you're running this in a directory that contains `1.txt`, `2.txt`, and a directory `3.d`.

Under those circumstances, this would expand to:

```
sudo mv /home/userA /home/userB /home/userC 1.txt 2.txt 3.d
```

That is to say, both globs are expanded -- the first to the list of entries in `/home`, an the subject to the list of files in the current working directory -- and the result is everything being moved into the directory `3.d`.

---

<sub>Flagged Community Wiki since this is an answer to an off-topic question.</sub>